Minimum eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix
I was solving a problem and got stuck on the following:
Let $[p] = \{1, \ldots, p\}$ where $p \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $P(n, r)$ denote the set of all injective functions from $[r]$ to $[n]$ and write a typical element as $\sigma = [\sigma(1), \ldots, \sigma(r)]$ where $1 \leq \sigma(i) \leq n$ and $\sigma(i)$'s are all distinct. The Hamming distance between two elements, $\sigma, \tau$ of $P(n, r)$, can be defined as the number of points in the domain they disagree on, i.e., the cardinality of $\{i \in [r] : \sigma(i) \neq \tau(i)\}$.
Order the elements of $P(n, r)$ as $\{\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_{^np_{r}}\}$ and construct a matrix of dimension $^np_{r} \times ^np_{r}$ whose $(i, j)$-th entry is $x^{d(i,j)}$ where $d(i,j)$ is the Hamming distance between $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$. Let $f_{(n,r)}(x)$ be the minimum eigenvalue of the matrix.
Using the Cauchy Interlacing Theorem, I managed to prove that $f_{(n,r)}(x) = (1 - x)^r$ when $x \in [0, 1]$. Now I am interested in $x \in \left(-\frac{1}{n - 1}, 0\right)$. I showed that $(1 - x)^{r-1}(1 + (r - 1)x)$ is an eigenvalue but am unable to check whether it is the minimum. I also think that in this interval
$
f_{(n,r)}(x) > f_{(n,r-1)}(x) > (1 + (n - 1)x)
$
for all $n \geq r > 1$. I have managed to prove that all eigenvalues will be integer polynomials in $x$ and $f_{(n,n)}(x) > f_{(n,n-1)}(x)$ for all $n$.
I need help in proving
$$
f_{(n,r)}(x) > f_{(n,r-1)}(x) > (1 + (n - 1)x).
$$
Any help will be highly appreciated and Thank you in advance!

But $(1 - x)^{-1} (1 + (r - 1)x)$ is not a polynomial in $x$, and it blows up at $x=1$ while eigenvalues must remain bounded

@FedorPetrov, I corrected it. It should have been (1−x)^{r-1}(1+(r−1)x).  The eigenvalues are polynomials can be seen from the fact that the matrix is in Bose-Mesner Algebra generated by the distance based Association Scheme

@bluebird The symbolic matrix A(x) in the indeterminate x that you define above belongs to the Bose--Mesner algebra of the association scheme of injective functions/partial permutations (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.07336 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.04500 for more details). If you are still interested in this problem, I have some unpublished results that would allow one to write down the eigenvalues of this matrix, each as a function of n,r,x, but it would take quite a bit of extra effort. Perhaps you can prove what you need just using the links above; otherwise, shoot me an email.

Consider the usual Hamming scheme with a (larger) $n^{r}\times n^{r}$ matrix
$D$ of Hamming distances (entries $D_{ij}=d(i,j)$) for the $n^{r}$ $r$-tuples with elements taken from the set $[n]$. (Duplicates in the $r$-tuples are allowed, unlike in the case of interest.) Let $Z$ be the
corresponding matrix with entries $x^{d(i,j)}$. The matrix of interest $X$
is a submatrix of $Z$, so we approach this through Cauchy interlacing.
Recounting the well-known features of the Bose-Mesner algebra for the usual
Hamming scheme, e.g. Ref 1, the
adjacency matrices $A_{k}$ are related to $D$ and $Z$ by
$$
D=\sum_{k=0}^{r}kA_{k}
$$
$$
Z=\sum_{k=0}^{r}x^{k}A_{k}
$$
The matrices $A_{k}$ (and also $D$ and $Z$) are a mutually commuting set of
normal matrices that have common eigenvectors, and they can be
simultaneously diagonalized to find the eigenvalues $\Lambda $ of $Z$ in
terms of the eigenvalues $\Lambda _{k}$ of the $A_{k}$.
$$
\Lambda =\sum_{k=0}^{r}x^{k}\Lambda _{k}
$$
where $\Lambda ,\Lambda _{k}$ are diagonal matrices of eigenvalues. The
distinct eigenvalues in $\Lambda _{k}$, $\{\Lambda _{k}(i),$ $i=0,\ldots ,r\}$
are given by values of the Krawtchouk
polynomials
$$
K(r,n,k,z)=\sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{j}(n-1)^{k-j}\binom{z}{j}\binom{r-z}{k-j}
$$
at $z=i$. The generating function for these at different $k$ values is given
by
$$
\left( 1+(n-1)x\right) ^{r-z}(1-x)^{z}=\sum_{k=0}^{r}x^{k}K(r,n,k,z)
$$
and comparing with the formula for $\Lambda $ we see this is precisely the
formula for the distinct eigenvalues of $Z$, i.e., they are
$$
\left( 1+(n-1)x\right) ^{r-i}(1-x)^{i},~i=0,\ldots ,r
$$
For $x\in (0,1)$ both factors are positive. Since $(1-x)<1$, $(1-x)^{i}$
decreases as $i$ increases. Since $\left( 1+(n-1)x\right) >1,$ $\left(
1+(n-1)x\right) ^{r-i}$ deceases as $i$ increases. The minimum eigenvalue is
therefore at the greatest $i$ value, i.e., the minimum eigenvalue is $%
(1-x)^{r}$. By Cauchy, the minimum eigenvalue of $X$ is $\geq (1-x)^{r}$.
For $x\in (-1/(n-1),0)$ both factors are again positive. We have $\left(
1+(n-1)x\right) $ positive and less than $1$, with magnitude decreasing as $i$
decreases. The factor $(1-x)^{i}$ is positive and greater than $1$ and
decreases as $i$ decreases. The minimum eigenvalue is therefore at the least $i$
value, i.e., the minimum eigenvalue is $\left( 1+(n-1)x\right) ^{r}$. By
Cauchy, the minimum eigenvalue of $X$ is $\geq \left( 1+(n-1)x\right)
^{r}$.
1: P. Delsarte and V.I. Levenshtein, Association Schemes and Coding Theory,
IEEE Trans Information Theory, 44 (1998) 2477 - 2504.
Edit: There is not a consistent minimum eigenvalue for $x\in \left( -\frac{1}{n-1},0\right) $
For the case of $n=4$, $r=3$ for example, the eigenvalues are
$$
(1-x)^{2},~(1-x)^{2}(1+2x),~(1-x)^{2}(1+3x),~(1-x)^{3},~(1-x)(1+x^{2}),~(1-x)(1+3x+4x^{2}),~1+3x+9x^{2}+11x^{3}
$$
which are plotted here:

In the range $(0,1)$ the green curve $(1-x)^{3}$ is consistently the lowest.
Although in $\left( -\frac{1}{3},0\right) $ the eigenvalues are all
consistently positive, the curves intersect in multiple places in this
range, so one of the polynomials is not consistently the minimum eigenvalue.
(Consistency seems to hold for the $Z$ matrix above.)

As far as I can see, the $^{n}p_{r}\times ~^{n}p_{r}$ submatrices of the
$A_{k}$ do not always satisfy $A_{i}A_{j}$ being a linear combination of the
$A_{k}$ and so the smaller problem is not a true association scheme. Perhaps this is not a
requirement to find a similar generating function for $X$, but I didn't
pursue this.

How can you conclude this ((1 + (n - 1)x)^r > (1 + (n - 1)x))? Specifically, if (g < 1), then (g^r < g) for all natural numbers (r > 1).

Sloppy of me - I've changed it.

I can actually prove the minimum eigenvalue to be strictly greater than $(1+(n-1)x)^r$, in fact $\geq (1+(n-1)x)...(1+(n-r)x).$, I want to show even this inequality is strict as suggested by numerical evidences
